# Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

Tags: sql-server, database, timeout, sqlconnection, connection-timeout

hi I'm getting an error `Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding`.
I'm alredy changed the connect `timeout = 60000` and in database my procedure is executes in 43sec. so plz give me some perfect solution

thank you

Comment: There isn't enough information here to tell what you're doing, or what could be causing your problem.

Comment: @amer Please provide more details. Which languages are you working in? Are you using a library, framework, CMS? What is the server technology you're communicating with? Are you attempting to query a database, read a file? Currently your question lacks very vital information which may result in it being closed.

Comment: @Jonathan the error is a typical ado.net / sql error but its true more information could have helped. Atleast some sensible tagging.

Comment: You will need to give some more information in order for anyone to solve this. Can you post some relevant code for example?

Comment: Please do not ask the same question repeatedly. The community has already told you that you are not providing enough information to be able to help you. Please update **this** question with more information then flag to have it re-opened. Thanks

Comment: @amer khan Please review my answer. I'm sure it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should note that [`Timeout` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout.aspx) for `SqlConnection` object and [`Timeout` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx) for `SqlCommand` object are different properties.
By default command timeout is set to 30 seconds. Set it to 60, and your issue will be solved:

```
commandObject.Timeout = 60;
```

But most likely that you should change your SQL procedure or split it to some parts

Comment: the same answer was given yesterday!

Comment: @Pinakin Shah Can you explain, why did you downvote it? I just added advice to refactor the sql.

Comment: Your answer was same as given by me yesterday and I didnt check you had some added advice. Will give you a vote up :)

Comment: @Pinakin Shah updated the answer, so please, remove your down vote :) (I'll never ever edit my old questions again)

Comment: Any reason for downvote?

Answer (score 4):

Try running your SQL query using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, and click the "Estimated Execution Plan" button.  This will tell you if you have any indexes missing.  Adding the missing indexes should speed up your query.

Answer (score 1):

Increase the query timeout. Connection timeout is only on the connection time. Presuming you are using SqlCommand, there is a timeout property in there.