# The timeout period elapsed

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2008

I have developed a software and installed it on three different client machine.

All is well but on a last one the following message comes:

> The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the
>   server on is not responding

Comment: Welcome on stack overflow!  This question is very vague and would be difficult for anyone to answer.  So, unless you correct it, I'm sure it will get voted down and closed.  I recommend adding more details and specifics.  For instance, what operation is your application performing which is timing out?

Comment: Here's a similar question where you can also see which additional details are helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602395/timeout-expired-the-timeout-period-elapsed-prior-to-completion-of-the-operation

Answer (score 1):

Check [this answer on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6746845/897326).

Also check [this discussion on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/153279/Timeout-expired-The-timeout-period-elapsed-prior-t).

If it does not help, try googling for this query:

> The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the
>   server on is not responding